# Переадресация Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Здравствуйте.Проблема в следующем: localhost:81 = localhost:81/home - то есть дубль.
Подскажите как сделать редирект с localhost:81/home на localhost:81 или хотя бы заблокировать /Home. SEO ругается
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько вариантов:

1. Убрать значения по умолчанию в Default Route и добавить новое правило, которое будет отображать `/` в Home/Index

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Home",
       url: "",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
       constraints: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } 
   );

   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
   );
   ```
2. Настроить Redirect в IIS
3. В /Home/Index проверять, что url у вас именно `/` и делать редирект, но я бы воздержался от этого способа

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       // здесь нужно учитывать случай, когда приложение развернуто не в корне сайта.
       if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath != "/")
           return RedirectPermanent("/");
   ```